# Is covariant return type overriding according jls?

Tags: java, compilation, overriding

Just say, that point of my question is learn to understand jls. I believe that all in jls are true.

Consider next snippet from jls:

> 8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods)
>
> An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance
>   method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:
>
> C is a subclass of A.
>
> The signature of m1 is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.
>
> Either:
>
> m2 is public, protected, or declared with default access in the same
>   package as C, or
>
> m1 overrides a method m3 (m3 distinct from m1, m3 distinct from m2),
>   such that m3 overrides m2.
>
> Moreover, if m1 is not abstract, then m1 is said to implement any and
>   all declarations of abstract methods that it overrides.

Go to subsignature declaration:

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a
>   method m2 if either:
>
> m2 has the same signature as m1, or
>
> the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature
>   of m2.

About same signature:

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and
>   argument types.

Which rule does allow to use covariant return type?

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question explaining why do you think it is a contradiction.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza **R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 (§8.4.4), is a subtype of R2.** if R1 is Integer then R2 may be Integer or Number or Object

Comment: it is doesn't compatibility with

    **The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:

    m2 has the same signature as m1, or

    the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.**

Comment: That is correct. Again, what don't you understand? Note that method signature doesn't involve the return type.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I forgot consider about rule of "Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types." Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of these rules allows covariant return types.  Signatures of a method refer to the method name and the types and order of its arguments, but not to the return type.

[From JLS, Section 8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> *This rule allows for covariant return types - refining the return type of a method when overriding it.*

That refers to [Section 8.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5), which states:

> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2 iff any of the following is true:
>
> - If R1 is void then R2 is void.
> - If R1 is a primitive type then R2 is identical to R1.
> - If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true:
>
>   - R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 (§8.4.4), **is a subtype of R2**.
>   - R1 can be converted to a subtype of R2 by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9).
>   - d1 does not have the same signature as d2 (§8.4.2), and R1 = |R2|.

(emphasis mine)

That part I bolded allows covariant return types.

Comment: There's also a note that says *"This rule allows for covariant return types - refining the return type of a method when overriding it."* regarding your first citation.

Comment: contradiction  **An instance method m1, declared in class C, overrides another instance method m2, declared in class A iff all of the following are true:...**  and **R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 (§8.4.4), is a subtype of R2.**

Comment: @arshajii Funny, I just got the parts that I needed and missed that quote.  I've included it now.

Comment: @gstackoverflow How is that a contradiction?  The subclass method `d1` can declare a more narrow return type `R1` than the superclass method being overridden, `d2`.

Comment: if **If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration...**!!! only at this case!!! **then d1 must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error occurs **

Comment: contradictin **R1, adapted to the type parameters of d2 (§8.4.4), is a subtype of R2** and  requirements of subsignature

Comment: @gstackoverflow The "is a subtype of R2" clause is stating one of the ways that `d1` can be "return-type-substitutable" without a compiler error.  That is not a contradiction, it's part of the definition.

Comment: @gstackoverflow What the JLS is doing is *adding* another requirement for a method to override. *In addition* to the signature of `m1` being a subsignature of `m2`, `m2` must be be return-type substitutable.

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry I forgot consider that **Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.**

Comment: @gstackoverflow But the argument types aren't the return types, correct?