# Does something like a <getClass()> generic parameter exist in Java?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I would like to have an abstract method that has a parameter of the exact class of the instance.
For example:

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract void aFunc(???? newInst);
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    void aFunc(Bar newInst);
}
class Baz extends Foo {
    @Override
    void aFunc(Baz newInst);
}
```

Effectively I would like to be able to access all subclass fields and methods without having to check and cast the newInst parameter. (As the function would be called from a central handler location that does the checks and casts).

I know I can do this by parameterising Foo with `Foo<T extends Foo>`, but I would ideally like to avoid declaring subclasses as `class Name extends Foo<Name>` if possible.

I doubt this is possible, and I have been unable to find anything on the topic, but I would just like to confirm that there is nothing i have missed.

Comment: "I would ideally like to avoid declaring subclasses as class Name extends Foo<Name> if possible" Why? This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Remember that `getClass()` is evaluated at runtime, whereas generics are a purely compile-time concept. Thus you can't do something in generics involving `getClass()`.

Comment: why you want to do that ?

Comment: other way is you can use `generics` with `lambada` expression

Comment: @AndyTurner I am aware that getClass() is evaluated at runtime, but surely the class name could be compiled the same way type erasure works. The reason I would like to avoid it is because it seems somewhat redundant specifying the class name twice.

Comment: @asteriskNinja What do you mean by using generics with lambda? Surely I would still have to specify the class using generics, so all it would save is declaring the inherited function, which is the bit I'm not bothered about, I would just like to avoid typing the class name twice.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem.  Whichever parts are specific to each subclass should be delegated to separate abstract methods, implemented by each subclass, which the superclass calls.  Under no circumstances should Foo need to know about the fields of subclasses;  that is the business of each respective subclass.

Comment: @VGR It was intended to be part of an API, so I could not create functions for each subclass, as I do not know all the subclasses. I will resort to having to cast the argument in the implementation, as for the sake of a single cast, it isn't worth the hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta-Comment:

the thing that you would like to have does break polymorphism: now you cannot use `Bar` or `Baz` everywhere you can use `Foo` because they have an aFunc signator that is not compatible anymore.

However, what you *can do* is have a return type that is more specific:

```
class Foo {
  Foo aFunc();
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  @Override
  Bar aFunc();
}
```

is valid. You can use an instance of Bar instead of Foo and call its `aFunc` method; then you can use the result of that method also as an instance of Foo. Therefore [JLS allows for covariant return types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23618392/112964) since Java 1.5.

Comment: Part of what I wanted was to be able to copy information to a separate instance of the same class, so I would need the parameter, but this is useful for a slightly different way of doing it, having the second class instantiation called by `Bar.createNew();` returning an instance of Bar instead of Foo, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who commented to help.

The correct way to do this is by declaring the class as `class Bar extends Foo<Bar>` and for the sake of simplicity, I will just pass Foo as the parameter and make all subclasses cast the argument themselves (if they need to).